# Logic with spacing when finding remainder

Tags: c, division, spacing

so I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
int i,k,m,l;
int add=0;
for(i=1;i<11;i++)
{
    printf("%-2d: ",i);
    for(k=i;k>0;k--)
    {
        m=i/k;
        if(i%k==0)
        {
            m=i/k;
            add=add+m;
            printf("%d ",m);
        }
        else
            printf("  ");
    }
    for(l=(10-i);l>0;l--)
        printf("  ");
    printf("| %d \n",add);  
    add=0;
   }
```

}

Now that code finds the remainders all fine, but I am having problems with the spacing between the divisions (pretty much the else statement).

this is what my program outputs:

```
 1: 1                             |  1 
 2: 1  2                          |  3 
 3: 1     3                       |  4 
 4: 1     2  4                    |  7 
 5: 1           5                 |  6 
 6: 1        2  3  6              | 12 
 7: 1                 7           |  8 
 8: 1           2     4  8        | 15 
 9: 1                 3     9     | 13 
10: 1              2        5  10  | 18
```

and this is what I need it to look like:

```
 1:  1                            |  1
 2:  1  2                         |  3
 3:  1     3                      |  4
 4:  1  2     4                   |  7
 5:  1           5                |  6
 6:  1  2  3        6             | 12
 7:  1                 7          |  8
 8:  1  2     4           8       | 15
 9:  1     3                 9    | 13
10:  1  2        5             10 | 18
```

So, I need all the same numbers to line up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to fix some lines, please, see the comments below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
int i,k,m,l;
int add=0;
for(i=1;i<11;i++)
{
    printf("%2d: ",i); // align to rigth
    for(k=1;k<=i;k++) // Invert loop order
    {
        m=i/k;
        if(i%k==0)
        {
            // m=i/k; Remove it. Duplicated!
            add=add+m;
            printf("%2d ",k); // use 2 digits and print k
        }
        else
            printf("   "); // three spaces
    }
    for(l=(10-i);l>0;l--)
        printf("   "); // three spaces
    printf("| %2d \n",add); // use 2 digits for print  
    add=0;
   }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't give the right output, infact it does all the remainders in the wrong order.

Comment: @user2097648 Did you update: printf("%2d ",m) to printf("%2d ",k)?

Comment: ohhhh yes, that small little change, I'm sorry I didn't catch that but thank you it works perfectly now :)